# Problem with connecting to API after build

Tags: angular

I'm creating a website where backend and frontend are separate projects.
After I finished creating the API (Django REST), I hosted it on Pythonanywhere and everything worked fine. It was able to connect to the hosted API.
However, the connection only works if the frontend-project (Angular 9) is running at localhost. After building the project and hosting it on AWS (S3 Static website hosting) it fails to connect to the API. No error occurs in the console. It just fails to retrieve the data. Moreover, the connection completely "blocks" the API. When the AWS frontend tries to connect to the API, no other connection is possible.

I don't think the AWS settings are a problem. If I upload simple script with AJAX requests to my API, it works fine, data is transferred correctly. (BTW. I tried to host my frontend on Netlify and I get exactly the same problem).
Probably building the Angular project is incorrect.
On local host, when i type:
`ng serve`
it works OK. I can connect to hosted API.

After building:
`ng build --prod --aot --output-path path/to/directory/`
there is the problem I described.
What could be the reason? Should I change any settings before building? Or build with another command?

EDIT:
Network-Request tabs:
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you see any requests going through in the network tab of the UI application ?

Comment: @arbghl Yes, but requests to my API are shown as OPTIONS (not GET). Without any status code.

Comment: OPTIONS is just a pre flight request to check whether the server is set up to take the requests. it could be CORS. 
Probably check the server logs for more information.

Comment: @arbghl I waited more. Ater 2-3 min Network tab throws errors. Finally, GET request appears with "CORS missing allow origin" nad OPTIONS with "501 gateway timeout".
In server logs there are 2 messages: "SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request" and "uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 306] during GET"

Comment: you probably need to set up request and response headers on your api and the UI call. May check your nginx conf file for timeouts and allowed headers.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: Share info also in developer console in network tab request infos please

Comment: @pc_coder  Which one exactly? In "request" tab only "Headers" is not empty. I have edited orginal post, with this info.

Comment: Did you enable CORS on django app ?

Comment: You are getting blocked from server due to cors policy. Enable cors in service

Comment: @pc_coder I have enabled CORS, CREDENTIALS, HEADERS etc. Everything is set as '*'. I have no problem connecting in any other way. The app connects correctly if works on localhost. I can connect to the API from the AWS bucket via AJAX script. Only app after build doesn't work.